# Should I be exporting members of a static lib consumed by a dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker

I'm using MSVC. And I have been reading around, I know this type of thing is a regular problem, just looking for some clarity!

I've got a hierarchy of static libraries, namely an interface library and an implementation library. I am trying to bundle them into a dll, but am having issues with figuring out when I should be using `__declspec(dllexport)` on members.

For example, I have an interface class `IInstance` that lives in `Interface.lib`

```cpp
class IInstance : public IModule
    {
    public:
        IInstance() : IModule() {}
        virtual ~IInstance() {}
        static API_TYPE const ModuleCategory category;       
    };
```

Another static lib (`System.lib`) provides one implementation:

```cpp
 class DefaultInstance : public IInstance
    {
    public:
        DefaultInstance();
        ~DefaultInstance();

    private:
```

And I want to link both those .libs into a .dll.
Another different static lib will include the header of the interface class.

One example of an issue I'm having is the `ModuleCategory` in `IInstance`. You can see I have `API_TYPE` ready to be either `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)`, depending on a preprocessor definition, e.g.

```cpp
#ifdef MY_PROJECT_DLL 
#pragma message("Building with DLL exports" )
#define API_TYPE __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#pragma message("Building with DLL imports" )
#define API_TYPE __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

From what I've read, when I'm building the DLL, I should be using a preprocessor definition set up in the DLL project (e.g. MY_PROJECT_DLL), however I'm not seeing that being picked up by the referenced .lib project, that is I see output like this **when building the DLL**:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: System, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>DefaultInstance.cpp
1>Building with DLL imports
1>Building with DLL imports
...
2>------ Build started: Project: MyNativeDLL, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>SomeOtherThing.cpp
2>Building with DLL exports
2>Building with DLL exports
2>Building with DLL exports
```

Should this be the case? I was expecting to see the static library pick up the MY_PROJECT_DLL defined in the dll project?

EDIT:
I've started building the static libs with MY_PROJECT_DLL defined as well. Other libraries that include headers from these libs then see `API_TYPE` as `__declspec(dllimport)`.

Working through unresolved externals one by one but this looks to be a probable solution

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for me was two-fold.

First, the static libs needed the preprocessor definition set in the project so that they used `__decl(dllexport)`.

Secondly - and this was the bit I couldn't find anywhere else obvious - the default linking of the static libs by the dynamic library meant that even though the symbols were exported in the `.lib` files, they weren't included in the final `.dll` unless they were actually used.

The best solution to this for me is to link the `.obj` files created when building the `.lib` files.
This guarantees (not sure how solid the guarantee is!) the symbols in the `.obj` make it into the `.dll`.
There are other ways to achieve this, such as having a dummy file that uses every function that is required, for example.

In visual studio there is a property on the reference item (I'm using project references to link the static libraries) called "Use Library Dependency Inputs".
Set this to true, and the `.obj` file of the static library is linked rather than the `.lib`, and all the symbols are included in the resulting .dll.

really good post mentioning the linking issue [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140321-00/?p=1433)